# Force WordPress to load a specific template

Tags: customization, templates

How would I force WordPress by code to load a template file on my home page? I know how to do it via the backend but I would like to create a plugin and have the option to set the front page from inside the plugin.

Basically, I am looking for the code to force loading a template when the home page is being loaded. So instead of the `index.php` it would load the plugin template. I can't find anything about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your *home* page, you either can set up a template file [`home.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Home_Page_display) (archive) or [`front-page.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Front_Page_display) (static page). In the according file, you can do whatever you want. Run additional queries, load content from whatever source etc.

If this is not what you want, then you can have a look at the [`template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter hook.
If you want/need to do more than just load a specific template file, you might want to have a look at the [`template_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) action hook.

Comment: don't use `template_redirect` to modify which template is loaded, that's what the [`template_include`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) filter is for.

Comment: i was plannning on using 'if ( ! is_admin() ) ' . Which one should i use?

Comment: @Milo I incorporated your comment into the answer. Of course, you are right. When just swapping out the template file, the filter is all you need.